# Not able to track sql error in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am reading query from property file in my spring batch program. Whenever I make any mistake in sql, I don't get any SQL exception but my job fails and the program terminates. Any idea about how to get SQL exception in such case.
For example - I deliberately gave a wrong table name in my query, instead of getting any sql error i got below exception in log.

```
2017-05-16 14:53:47,652 ERROR App                       main  - Exception thrown : 
org.springframework.batch.core.UnexpectedJobExecutionException: Step failure: the delegate Job failed in JobStep.
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.job.JobStep.doExecute(JobStep.java:120)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:162)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:141)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at com.cat.pdc.batch.job.App.main(App.java:40)
2017-05-16 14:53:47,654 INFO  App                       main  - main finally ExitStatus: FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add a Listener and intercept the Exception for logging or whatever you need.

Comment: Here are you suggesting about adding a jobExecution listener? I have implemented it but when this error occurs the controls does not exactly goes to listener. Below is code snippet. If you have any other example plz share it

public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
  try{
  // code for sending mail
  }catch(ApplicationException e){
   logger.error("Exception when update the entry for the job :", e);
  
   
  }

Comment: You could e.g. put a listener on the ItemReader since the problem seems to be there. See how you could implement ItemReaderListener (https://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-listeners-example/). You should use the function onReadError.

Comment: Tried what you suggested, din't work out. I kept some logs in onReadError function , even that was not printed.